# RegEx: Find Uppercase-Words after a specific string

Tags: regex

I tried hard to find a solution, but failed. A (very long) string ends like this:

> ...   destination: US, NL, UK, FRA, GER

The goal is:

- find all UPPERCASE-words (not only the mentioned above)
- with one, two or three letters
- only consider words after `destination:`

I finished the loop and successfully read all two-letter words of the whole string into a list:

```
@"\b[A-Z][A-Z]\b"
```

But more precison is needed.

Any regex-expert can help?

Comment: would `destination: US, NL` (both at the same time) be valid, or does yor example mean, that it either has to be `destination: US` or `destination: UK`?

Comment: @dognose I believe it is `destination: US, NL, ...`

Answer (score 0):

`@"destination.*?([A-Z]+)\b"` this is your regexp
`+` means one or more times
`.*` means any character 0 or more times. and `?` sign after that means lazy regexp. It will match characters until it **finds** the first uppercase. Without that sign in string "destination: ABCD" `.*` will match ": ABC"
after matching word you need will be in group 1. I don't know which language are you using

Comment: why are u using `.*?` when `:\s*` would be the more accurate solution according to tcs question? Also he states, that it needs to be 1 to 3 letter codes - so don't use `+` but `{1,3}` instead. `@"destination:\s*([A-Z]{1,3})"`

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

Here is an example in C#:

```
string regex = @"destination:\s*([A-Z]{1,3})(?:(?:,\s*)([A-Z]{1,3}))*";
var m = Regex.Match("... destination: US, NL, UK, FRA, GER", regex);

if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    if (m.Groups[2].Success) {
        foreach (var capture in m.Groups[2].Captures) {
            Console.WriteLine(capture.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
US
NL
UK
FRA
GER
```